# Dropdown values aren't visible on windows

Tags: html, css, layout

I've made a form with 3 dropdowns with a background image:
https://woobox.com/jmurnq

But the values aren't visible on Chrome and IE (Windows).

In firefox, none of the placeholders are visible.

Comment: In chrome, values are visible. only the placeholders are missing. Can you add a code snippet for better understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove padding-top and padding-bottom form **#input .column-3 select** add padding like **padding: 0 30px**

Comment: Yes, the padding did the trick. It seems that the padding "clips" the text. But don't know why.
I've deleted the padding-top and bottom and added height 60px.